# Need starting point for developing a "security app" for Android

Tags: android, security

I'm not sure where to begin on this. For my final project in my Android programming course, I have the following idea for an app, designed for people paranoid about accessing their phone without their permission:

It runs in the background. Every time the phone is unlocked (or unsuccessfully unlocked) the front facing camera will snap a photo of whoever has unlocked the device. The app keeps track of a running list of apps that have been accessed since the list has last been reset (ex: Jill knows that Jack unlocked her phone because of the picture the app took, and he browsed through her text messages and pictures since she set the phone down).

I want the picture to be saved within the app, not within the devices photo app. I want to display the apps accessed as a running (resettable) list, with an approximate time that the app was opened. Furthermore, I want the app to not be kill-able simply (through the app manager, for instance), and password protected as well, possibly disguised as another app.

Any idea where to begin on some of this? I appreciate any help whatsoever, thanks a ton.

Comment: Won't the lock PIN stop any unauthorised accesses?

Comment: I'm assuming that the unauthorized person accessing the phone has somehow learned the pin

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I already thought about that kind of app but there is a big problem: there is no `Intent` for an unsuccessful login attempt. Thus, your service can not know if there was an attempt.</strike>

**Edit:** as @CommonsWare stated, there actually is an `Intent` for [Device Administrators](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html)

Comment: "there is no Intent for an unsuccessful login attempt" -- yes there is, if your app is a properly-configured [device administrator](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) requesting that capability.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thanks, did not know that. pcd13: Here you have a starting point - Use Device Administration :)

Answer (score 0):

One challenge you will face, is that it's rather difficult to detect which applications have been opened. The only way that comes to mind, is through an accessibility service, but I'm not familiar with the details in implementing that approach.

Detecting failed login attempts means registering your application as a device administrator, as Mark of CommonsWare mentioned.

The challenge here is that your application will need to guide the user through setting the app up through accessibility tools and as a device administrator.

I hope this gives some insight!